# Issue testing bot in Azure portal : "Unable to determine function entry point"

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am developing a chatbot using the Microsoft Bot Framework. I have been developing my bot in my local environment using the bot emulator and it works fine. However, when I try testing in in the Azure portal, it gives the error message:

> "Exception while executing function: Functions.messages. mscorlib: Unable to determine function entry point. If multiple functions are exported, you must indicate the entry point, either by naming it 'run' or 'index', or by naming it explicitly via the 'entryPoint' metadata property."

[image: error message]

I have several helper functions besides the dialogs I defined for the bot and I am also passing in callbacks for those functions. What does the error mean and how can I fix it?

Edit:The source code is on https://github.com/jzcluo/BubbleBot/blob/master/messages/index.js

RESOLVED : So it turned out I had to use botbuilder_azure.BotServiceConnector instead of the builder.ChatConnector. That solved the issue.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide your source code or a link to it rather than just the error message.

Comment: I just added the link

Comment: So have you got a function called run or index or have a entryPoint metadate entry like the error tells you to do?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dijkgraaf, I tried adding a function called 'run' and it still gives me the error, and I am not sure where to add the entryPoint metadata.